# How to write a predicate for Streaming.Prelude.takeWhile

Tags: haskell, streaming, monads

I'm writing a program to consume a JSON API endpoint. The tricky part is that I want to keep iterating pages (by passing a `_page` parameter), and the iteration should stop once the API returns an empty list (note that this means we have to look into the response to decide if we should stop iterating).

I'm using `servant` to make it easy to call the API, and it is not difficult to write a recursive function to collect the results and terminate on the above-mentioned condition. But this can use a lot of memory if there are a lot of pages of results.

So I started looking into the `streaming` library. I've managed to create a stream of API calls, but am struggling to write the terminating condition. I really want to write the terminating condition without executing the client's `runClientM` method. So rather than writing a recursive function which explicitly calls the API and collects the results, I'd like to do something like:

```
map runClientM $ takeWhile hasData $ map createPageRequest $ [1..]
```

I got to the point where I can create and run a stream of requests, but cannot write the terminating condition. I'm not sure if I cannot get the types to work out because I'm missing a function to tie all the types together (`liftM` or something...), or because the type system is stopping me from doing what I'm trying to do because it is stupid (the whole *make illegal states representable* idea).

Anyway, here is the code (I need something to replace `_`, `predicate1` and `predicate2` don't compile). Any pointers will be appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack

{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

import Servant.Client
import Network.HTTP.Client (newManager, defaultManagerSettings)

import Data.Proxy
import Servant.API

import Data.Aeson
import GHC.Generics

import Streaming
import qualified Streaming.Prelude as S

-- data type
data BlogPost = BlogPost
  { id :: Integer
  , title :: String
  } deriving (Show, Generic)

instance FromJSON BlogPost


-- api client
type API = "posts" :> QueryParam "_page" Integer :> Get '[JSON] [BlogPost]
api :: Proxy API
api = Proxy
posts :: Maybe Integer -> ClientM [BlogPost]
posts = client api


requestStream :: (Monad m) => Stream (Of (ClientM [BlogPost])) m ()
requestStream = S.takeWhile _ $ S.map posts $ S.each pages
  where
    pages = [Just p | p <- [1..]]
    predicate1 (Right v) = True
    predicate1 (Left e) = False
    predicate2 request = do
      r <- request
      case r of
        Right v -> return $ length v /= 0
        Left e -> return False


main :: IO ()
main = do
  manager' <- newManager defaultManagerSettings
  let url = ClientEnv manager' (BaseUrl Http "jsonplaceholder.typicode.com" 80 "")
  S.print $ S.mapM (\x -> runClientM x url) requestStream
  print "done"
```

EDIT: I'm just doing a `S.print` for now, but I will want to do some other action, like send this data to a database.

EDIT: Here is the error I'm getting when using `predicate1` for example. I don't understand why the actual type now has `Either a0 b0` instead of the `ClientM [BlogPost]` which is what it is without a call to `S.takeWhile`.

```
test.hs:37:17: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Either a0 b0’ with ‘ClientM [BlogPost]’
      Expected type: Stream (Of (ClientM [BlogPost])) m ()
        Actual type: Stream (Of (Either a0 b0)) m ()
    • In the expression:
        S.takeWhile predicate1 $ S.map posts $ S.each pages
      In an equation for ‘requestStream’:
          requestStream
            = S.takeWhile predicate1 $ S.map posts $ S.each pages
            where
                pages = [Just p | p <- [1 .. ]]
                predicate1 (Right v) = True
                predicate1 (Left e) = False
                predicate2 request
                  = do r <- request
                       ....
   |
37 | requestStream = S.takeWhile predicate1 $ S.map posts $ S.each pages
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

test.hs:37:42: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘ClientM [BlogPost]’ with ‘Either a0 b0’
      Expected type: Stream (Of (Either a0 b0)) m ()
        Actual type: Stream (Of (ClientM [BlogPost])) m ()
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘S.map posts $ S.each pages’
      In the expression:
        S.takeWhile predicate1 $ S.map posts $ S.each pages
      In an equation for ‘requestStream’:
          requestStream
            = S.takeWhile predicate1 $ S.map posts $ S.each pages
            where
                pages = [Just p | p <- [1 .. ]]
                predicate1 (Right v) = True
                predicate1 (Left e) = False
                predicate2 request
                  = do r <- request
                       ....
   |
37 | requestStream = S.takeWhile predicate1 $ S.map posts $ S.each pages
   |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: "predicate1 and predicate2 don't compile" - include the errors produced by your code.

Comment: @user2407038, I've added the compile error to the question.

Comment: I feel like the type of `takeWhile` is pretty obvious - to filter a `Stream (Of a)` you need a function `a -> Bool`. You have `Stream (Of (ClientM [BlogPost]))` but `predicate1` clearly takes an `Either` argument - this is why you get type errors related to `Either`. You need a function `ClientM [BlogPost] -> Bool` - I don't know how you would write this function, since you haven't really explained what it would do - you could also use `takeWhileM` and have a predicate `ClientM [BlogPost] -> M Bool` for some `M`